# 'Permalinks' only working on left hand side of Tumblr blog

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I've been at this for days trying to sort it out with absolutely no luck. The permalinks are only working with the photo posts on the left hand side of my blog (regardless of whether they are photo posts or re-blogs) and I have no idea why, I need all photo posts and re-blog (photo's) to be permalinks.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks very much.

Here's the blog: http://symbolsofwealth.tumblr.com/

And here's the code:

Anything else you might need just ask.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{Title}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
    {block:Description}
        <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
    {/block:Description}
<link href='http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/DHIm5wmgi/stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



        <meta name="color:Background" content="#ffffff"/>
        <meta name="color:Text" content="#000000"/>
        <meta name="color:Video Corner Fold" content="red">
        <meta name="font:Font" content="'BrownBold'">
        <meta name="if:Show Captions" content="0"/>
        <meta name="if:Uppercase Links" content="0">
        <meta name="if:Fade On Hover" content="0">
        <meta name="if:Show Tags on Index Page" content="0">
        <meta name="image:header" content="0"/>



<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>

<!–
var message=””;

function clickIE()
{if (document.all)
{(message);return false;}}

function clickNS(e) {
if
(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all))
{
if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}}

if (document.layers)
{document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.  onmousedown=clickNS;}
else
{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu  =clickIE;}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function(“return false”)
–>
</script>







<style type="text/css">

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('http://static.tumblr.com/e72d71d9df861d718427e82229f48499/yo2ke79/iMEn5bbly/tumblr_static_9kpmrzvkfosoo4o0g8k4g80oc.png')no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 15px 50% 0 50%;
  top: 0px;
  left: -300px;
  right: -300px;
  z-index: 4999;

}



body {
background-color:{color:Background};
font-family:{font:Font};
color:{color:Text};
font-size:17px;
line-height:25px;
}



a { 
padding-bottom:2px;
color:{color:Text};
text-decoration:none;
border-bottom:2px solid;
}
img {
border: none;
border : 0;
outline:none;
}
a img {
outline: none;
}
iframe#tumblr_controls {  
display:none;
}
#wrapper {
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:580px;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
position:relative;
margin: 50px auto; 
}
#post {
padding:40px;
}
#post img {
width:100%;
}
#post img:hover {
{block:IndexPage}
{block:IfFadeOnHover}
opacity:0.5;
{/block:IfFadeOnHover}
{/block:IndexPage}
}
#post embed, #post iframe {
width:100% !important;
}
#post .photoset a:first-child {
display:block !important;
border:0 !important;
padding:0 !important;
}
#post .photoset a {
display:none;
}
.title {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
position:fixed;
top:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.follow {
position:fixed;
margin: 0px 30% 0 16.3%;
bottom:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.archive {
position:fixed;
margin: 0px 20px 0 30%;
bottom:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.message {
position:fixed;
bottom:20px;
left:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.random {
position:fixed;
margin: 0px 0px 0 60%;
bottom:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
#toTop {
width:100%;
margin: 0px 0px 0 43%;
z-index:5000;
position:fixed;
display:none;
bottom:20px;
cursor:pointer;

}
.player {
background:#000;
}
ul.chat {
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#infscr-loading {
display:none !important;
}

.corner {
top:6px;
right:40px;
position:absolute;
padding:1em 1.5em;
margin:2em auto;
color:#fff;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:4000;
}
.corner:before {
content:"";
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
border-width:0 25px 25px 0;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#fff #fff {color:Video Corner Fold} {color:Video Corner Fold};
background:#fff;
display:block; width:0; /* Firefox 3.0 damage limitation */
}
{CustomCSS}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/4Wjm5wj58/disassemble_v3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#toTop').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header"></div>

{block:IfUppercaseLinks}<div style="text-transform:uppercase">{/block:IfUppercaseLinks}
<div class="title"><a href="/">{Title}</a></div>
<div class="archive"><a href="archive">Archive</a></div>
<div class="message"><a href="/ask">Message</a></div>
<div class="follow">{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Posts}<a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">Reblog</a> / {/block:Posts}{/block:PermalinkPage}<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/follow/{Name}">Follow</a></div>
<div class="random"><a href="/random">Random</a></div>
<div id="toTop">Back to top</div>
{block:IfUppercaseLinks}</div>{/block:IfUppercaseLinks}




<div id="wrapper">

{block:Posts}
<div id="post" 
{block:IndexPage}
{block:Post1}style="width:380px"{/block:Post1}
{block:Post2}style="width:410px"{/block:Post2}
{block:Post3}style="width:500px"{/block:Post3}
{block:Post4}style="width:290px"{/block:Post4}
{block:Post5}style="width:320px"{/block:Post5}
{block:Post6}style="width:460px"{/block:Post6}
{block:Post7}style="width:530px"{/block:Post7}
{block:Post8}style="width:280px"{/block:Post8}
{block:Post9}style="width:340px"{/block:Post9}
{block:Post10}style="width:400px"{/block:Post10}
{block:Post11}style="width:260px"{/block:Post11}
{block:Post12}style="width:370px"{/block:Post12}
{block:Post13}style="width:520px"{/block:Post13}
{block:Post14}style="width:310px"{/block:Post14}
{block:Post15}style="width:250px"{/block:Post15}
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}style="width:500px"{/block:PermalinkPage}
> 




{block:Text}
{block:Title}<a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a>{/block:Title}
{Body}
{/block:Text}

{block:Link}
<a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>
{block:Description}<div class="description">{Description}</div>{/block:Description}
{/block:Link}

{block:Quote}
<a style="border:0 !important" href="{Permalink}">"{Quote}"</a>
{block:Source}
<p>&mdash; {Source}</p>
{/block:Source}
{/block:Quote}





{block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}<a href="{Permalink}"><div style="border:none"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"  alt="{PhotoAlt}" border="0"></div></a>{/block:IndexPage}


{block:PermalinkPage}{LinkOpenTag}<div style="border:none"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/></div>{LinkCloseTag}{/block:PermalinkPage}

{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photo}




{block:Chat}
{block:Title}<h2>{Title}</h2>{/block:Title}
<ul class="chat">{block:Lines}<li class="user_{UserNumber}">{block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}</li>{/block:Lines}</ul>
{/block:Chat}

{block:Video}
{block:IndexPage}<a href="{Permalink}"><div class="corner"></div></a>{/block:IndexPage}
<div id="video"> 
{Video-500}
</div>
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Video}

{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage}<div class="photoset">{block:Photos}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"></a>{/block:Photos}</div>{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{Photoset-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photoset}

{block:Audio}
{block:AlbumArt}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{AlbumArtURL}"></a>{/block:AlbumArt}
<div class="player">{AudioPlayerBlack}</div>
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Audio}

{block:IfShowTagsOnIndexPage}{block:IndexPage}{block:Date}Posted {TimeAgo} and has {NoteCountWithLabel}{block:HasTags}<br>{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}{/block:Date}{/block:IndexPage}{/block:IfShowTagsOnIndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Date}Posted {TimeAgo} and has {NoteCountWithLabel}{block:HasTags}<br>{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}{/block:Date}{/block:PermalinkPage}

</div>
{/block:Posts}

{block:NextPage}<div id="page-nav"><a href="{NextPage}"></a>{/block:NextPage}

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: solved. My div container was covering the whole middle and right hand grids, because the z-index was set to be the top layer, i tightened up the div container. thanks

Comment: Good job! Add it as a solution and accept your answer! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. My div container was covering the whole middle and right hand grids, because the z-index was set to be the top layer, i tightened up the div container. thanks